# Symfony2: Add a prefix route to a bundle

Tags: symfony, routes

I am working with Symfony2 and I have a bundle that includes multiple controllers. I want to have a common prefix route for all of them.

Something like this:

bundle_path/controller1_path 
bundle_path/controller2_path 
bundle_path/controller3_path

etc.

Is there a way to do this without writing bundle_path into every single controller?

Comment: What the problem with that?

Comment: You can do this, you have to create your own RouteLoader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a *prefix* to alle the bundle's route in the routing.yml files. As Example:

```
acme_customer_area_frontend:
    resource: "@AcmeCustomerAreaFrontendBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /customer/frontend
```

Hope this help

Comment: thank you, just what I needed! It also works with annotations (which I use).  

acme_customer_area_frontend:
    resource: "@AcmeCustomerAreaFrontendBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /customer/frontend

Comment: Hi @Fromage please consider to upvote my answer if you consider it helpful

Comment: Just did, would have done earlier, but I needed a reputation score of 15 to do it (new user here) ;) Thanks again